# Why won't fullcalendar show up on my webpage?

Tags: html, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I'm just trying to get a blank calendar to show up on one of my web pages and I believe I have that bare minimum code to do that but it won't show up. My view looks like this:

```
<% content_for :title, "Marketing Schedule" %>
<body id='marketingSchedule'>
  <%= render 'layouts/menu', :page => 'marketing_schedule' %>
  <h1 class='marketingScheduleTitle'>Marketing Schedule</h1>
  <div id='msCalendar'></div>
</body>
```

Part of my coffescript looks like this:

```
else if $("body").attr("id") is "marketingSchedule"
        $(document).ready ->
            $("#msCalendar").fullCalendar
```

The calendar shows up on one of my other pages so everything with FullCalendar should be working but I can't figure out how to get a blank calendar on the Marketing Schedule Page. Do I have something wrong or do I need to add something more to one of my files?

Comment: Last line is incorrect, nullary function call is still like this `$("#msCalendar").fullCalendar()` otherwise impossible to distinguish between calling the function and merely referencing it.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: Good deal, that should help get the right people here. Check my edited comment, pretty sure that's your problem. Or at least part of your problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith That totally fixed it! However, the calendar on my other page is declared like this `$(document).ready ->
   $("#tsCalendar").fullCalendar` and works fine. Do you have any idea why that may be?

Comment: If you're passing arguments you don't need the parentheses: `$("#tsCalendar").fullCalendar 'foo'`. Otherwise, I have no idea because that shouldn't work.

Comment: I don't know, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @JaredSith:

Last line is incorrect, nullary function call is still like this `$("#msCalendar").fullCalendar()` otherwise impossible to distinguish between calling the function and merely referencing it.